# PHP simple_html_dom foreach

Tags: php, foreach, simple-html-dom

I'm getting html from different pages ($linkHtml) and want to get elements from those pages. With this I get Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object. If I move the second foreach out I get the result that I want from one page. How should I do to get the elements from all pages?

```
$url = 'http://page/';

foreach ($dataArray as $link) {
        $linkHtml = file_get_html($url . $link);

        foreach ($linkHtml->find('text') as $text) {

        }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that `file_get_html` is failing and returning a NULL, and that you need to check that it succeeds and you're getting back a proper object.

Answer (score 0):

I could't find any documentation on file_get_html() on php.net!? I would use

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents($url . $link)));
```

[file-get-contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

[domdocument.loadhtml](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php)